# If the value of a object is empty in a JSON file, it takes previous value

Tags: php, mysql, json, loops, pdo

I am inserting values in SQL database using PDP Prepared PDO statements from JSON file.

This is, how my code:

```
$requestno = 8
$maxrequest = 15
while ($requestno < $maxrequest)
{
    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/".$requestno."?api_key=456cec7xxxxxxxxxxxxxe0c834a");
    if ($response != FALSE) {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
    }

   $requestno++;

   <?php

   try {

       // prepare sql and bind parameters
       $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (firstname) 
                               VALUES (:firstname)");
       $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);

       // insert a row
       if ( $response["firstname"] != ""        )
       $tagline = $response["firstname"];
       $stmt->execute();

       echo "New records created successfully";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
       echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
   $conn = null;
}
?>
```

As you can see the url of JSON file include ".$requestno.", so I am retrieving data from multiple JSON files.

So what happenes here,  if firstname is empty in a JSON file, MYSQL inserts the previous JSON file firstname. How to fix it?

Please let me know, if u need more info.

Comment: What have you tried to fix this, yourself? Have you tried setting `$response = false`, before the `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Empty the variable at the beginning of the loop. `$firstname = '';` and ^^

Comment: All JSON Files have some value. So, it will never be false

Comment: Let me try Jon's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the variable $firstname at the start of each loop as mentioned by JonStirling in his comments like below,

```
while ($requestno < $maxrequest)
{
  $firstname = '';
  //your remaining code here
}
```

Issue: As you are not reseting your values, it takes the value assigned to it  in the previous iteration

Comment: I am getting this error

Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'firstname' at row 1

Comment: from where do you get the values for $firstname within the loop. I assumed that you will get them from $response. May be you are not getting the $firstname from the response or even you are not getting $response itself

Comment: Mymistake, i was getting a number from $firstname...fixed it.